# C - wcstok crashes at runtime

Tags: c, pointers, winapi

Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void Example()
{
  wchar_t Src[MAX_PATH];
  GetModuleFileNameW(0, Src, sizeof(Src));
  MessageBoxA(0, "IN", 0, 0);
  wchar_t *Dst = wcstok(Src, L"\\"); // Crashes here, at run-time!
  MessageBoxW(0, Dst, __T("Out"), 0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Example();
  return 0;
}
```

At runtime this application crashes at line 8. The question is why?

[wcstok() reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcstok/)

MSDN on [`GetModuleFileNameW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Please, post at least a minimal, complete example that compiles.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  What does the function that you've not shown do?  Is it a function from the Microsoft Windows API (and hence standard on Windows)?  If so, you should probably tag the question with something appropriate.  Otherwise, people like me say "What does the function (whose definition you didn't show) actually do?" because it is not familiar.  A URL to the function specification wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: It finds the location of the token in the given string and outputs its index in a pointer, 'Dst' in this case. Basically the function I've written (irrelevant to this question) takes a file path and gets the base file name from that path. For example INPUT `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test.exe`, and OUTPUT `Test.exe`.

Comment: Are you sure `GetModuleFileNameW` is not returning an error? In which case `Src` contains junk. Probably should check its return value.

Comment: Not reproducible for me... I changed `__T("Out")` to `L"Out"` so it would compile for me and it definitely doesn't crash. The second box shows `c:` like you were probably expecting.

Comment: I actually do check its return value, here, let me make it more clear as to how exactly I wrote this function.

Comment: Is this a cpp file or a c file? On Visual Studio 2015 it apparently makes a difference as to whether or not this will compile. The question is tagged c but I think a mod tagged it.

Comment: Note `GetModuleFileNameW` needs the size of the buffer in characters, not bytes.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Does Microsoft take that to mean `wchar_t`'s or  codepoints? They have a history of conflating UTF-16 with UCS-2

Comment: @TimSeguine *The size of the lpFilename buffer, in TCHARs* (so `wchar_t` in a Unicode build).

Comment: The third argument to `GetModuleFileName` is the *number of characters*, not the number of bytes, You will need to use `MAX_PATH`, or `sizeof Src / sizeof Src[0]`.  Make this fix and try it out and then update your question accordingly. Of course you also should test the return value and abort if the function returns `0`.

Comment: Also, check `Dst != NULL` before you call `MessageBox` afterwards. Possibly wcstok does not crash but returns null, and then you cause the crash by calling MessageBox.

Comment: "I actually do check its return value" - you need to post actual code that shows the problem, not some made-up example that you have not actually run

Comment: The question sounds like you are trying to reimplement, what the [Shell Path Handling Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559.aspx) already provide.